# Making a standalone IDE tool like STS from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ide

I need to create some standalone programming editor/tools, and I found [STS](http://www.springsource.org/spring-tool-suite-download) fits my need. STS like some combination of `eclipse + plugins + default setup`.

How one can make a tool like STS out of eclipse?

Comment: Do you write your own plugins? Do you need to brand it (e.g. supply custom splashscreen/icon)?

Comment: @Eugene: I need to brand it just like STS does. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a "product" if you need to create a custom Eclipse distribution with branding and such. [This article](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_create_an_Eclipse_product%3F) should be a good starting point.

You can list "features" (plugin collections" you want to include in your distribution in the product file. I would also recommend you start reading about Tycho.

Comment: @Eugene the link you posted has no content

Comment: @prosseek yes, that's the one. Unfortunately the learning curve is rather steep, as for me. Here's the example - http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Demo_Projects/RCP_Application